# Problem clicking elements using class and index

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

I'm trying to write code to automatically DM people on Instagram. Im stuck on getting the code to click on the DM button.

In UIautomatorviewer, there is no text or a resource-id, so I tried using the class.

[image]

When I run the code it doesn't click on the right thing. It clicks on the button **NEXT** to it.

Here is the code -

```
By path2 = By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[@index='3']"); 
driver.findElement(path2).click(); 
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Can anyone help? I'm new to this so i'm not very experienced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I can not see the entire XML I can not really tell what you did wrong but probably your xpath is not correct.
With UIAutomatorViewer you can save the XML and then you can test your xpath on it. Either with XMLSpy or an online tool like https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html.

Probably there are more android.widget.ImageView with index = 3 and I think appium selects the first one? So you could change your xpath to a more unique one like:

```
//android.widget.FrameLayout//android.widget.LinearLayout//android.widget.ImageView[@index='3']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on UIAutomator Viewer screen you can also use `content-desc` as shown below

```
By path2 = By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@content-desc,'Message')]");
driver.findElement(path2).click();
```